# Understanding fat queries and tree structures

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I still have some troubles understanding the concept of fat queries in Relay, especially about the part of the intersection logic to determine which data to re-fetch.

Up to now, I have build a simple hierarchical data structure with a `UserType` as root query (named `viewer`) which has a number of `projects` (of type `ProjectConnectionType`) associated with it. Each of this projects has another `projects` field (also of type `ProjectConnectionType`) to model an arbitrarily nested sub-project hierarchy.

I also have two higher order React components `ProjectList` and `ProjectListItem` to render this structure by conditionally expanding fragments (by using a Relay variable `expanded` within my list item component).

So far, this works fine and I am quite happy with it. The tricky part is now the `AddProject` mutation. I have created a mutation which takes a name and the `parentProjectId` as input (might be null for root projects) and creates a new node on the server side at the right location. After that, it should return the new `projectEdges` (which are appended using `RANGE_ADD` afterwards), as well as the `parentProject` or `viewer` so that I also can update the `subprojectCount` there.

In case of the viewer (unique global root query point) everything works fine as well. Relay correctly calculates the intersection and asks for the new data from the server. But when I try to add a sub-project, I keep getting a completely empty response without any output fields (besides the mutation id). My guess is that Relay seems to get the intersection wrong by not knowing how to map the `parentProject` field accordingly. I have already tried to add a `FIELDS_CHANGE` config for it as well as querying `parentProject: node(id: "$parentProjectId")` within my fat query (which wasn't working either).

What I am missing? I have read the documentation a couple of times now, but I still do not understand the concept of mutations and I feel already quite dumb.

Comment: Can you inline the `getFatQuery` and `getConfigs` you're using now?

Comment: Ping! I'd love to help, if you're at liberty to post some code.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm also interested in understanding this topic. I'v made another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585808/relayjs-fatquery-not-generating-expected-query) to show my specific case.